# Clear tokens on end session

Tags: identityserver3

Is there possibility to automatically clear tokens for a given client when user performs end session?
Or i have to manually clear them by calling token revocation endpoint (yes I'm working with reference tokens for this scenario)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `SignOutAsync` method in your user service. From there you know who the user is (the subject id) and can then delete the tokens using the token handle store.

Comment: Thanks Dominick.In the meantime I implemented this with token revocation (I have full control over client in this case), but I will improve and implement this as you proposed.

Comment: Hi Dominick. I might forgot to mention that I'm using resource owner flow. So I do not have id token to pass.